# iOSのステータスバーに表示される「前のアプリに戻る」を表示させない

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity2d

Unityで開発を行っています。
iOSアプリにステータスバーを表示させているのですが、「前のアプリに戻る」の表示をさせたくありません。

```
void _HidesBackButton()
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)UnityGetGLViewController();
    navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

といったプラグインを作成して呼び出しているのですが「前のアプリに戻る」の表示はされてしまいました。
こちらどうすれば表示をさせないように出来ますでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

その部分はナビゲーションバーの戻るボタンとは違うものなのでそのコードで表示を消すことはできません。

また、ステータスバーに表示されるオブジェクトを操作するAPIは提供されていないので、通常のiOSアプリ開発においてもその表示を正規の方法でカスタマイズすることはできません。

よって、ステータスバーを非表示にてしまう以外に方法はありません。

Comment: 了解しました、ありがとうございます